# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes while importing flask_wtf

Tags: python, wtforms

I am trying to create forms for 'user registration' on a website. While trying to import flask_wtf module in Sublime Text 3 using the following input:

```
import flask_wtf
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\Desktop\Python Course Udemy\practice\Flask_blog\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flask_wtf
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .csrf import CSRFProtect, CsrfProtect
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\csrf.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wtforms import ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wtforms\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wtforms import validators, widgets
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wtforms\validators.py", line 9, in <module>
    import email_validator
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\email_validator\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import dns.resolver
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 36, in <module>
    import dns.message
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\message.py", line 24, in <module>
    import dns.wire
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\wire.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dns.name
  File "C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\name.py", line 26, in <module>
    import idna          # type: ignore
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your source files are messed up. Try to reinstall the `dns` library. If it does not help, manually edit the file `C:\Users\Aadish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\name.py` to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried to reinstall 'dns'. However, that did not help. I tried to manually edit the file but could not find the error(I am new to programming). So I ended up reinstalling python itself. Now the issue is resolved. Thank you for your help.